# kotlin navigation components set title crash

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm using `navigation` components and `bottomNavigationView` together. When I switch the tabs back and forth many times, then I got crash message:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5190)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5162)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.addSystemView(Toolbar.java:1528)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:777)
    at com.atp.newarchitecture.activity.AppActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(AppActivity.kt:119)
```

The code is:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _,
                                                        destination,
                                                        argument ->

    binding.toolbar.title = resources.getString(when (destination.id) {
            R.id.fragmentId -> R.string.fragmentTitle
            //... more ids
})
```

the layout file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/login_text_input_layout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
            tools:text="@string/selected_count" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_tip_root"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/quadruple_margin"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/loading_background_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know the crash message means one view should only has a parent, but seems no `addView` here. Wondering if every time `binding.root.title` assign call `addView`? Any help? Thanks!

**EDIT**：

```
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-beta02")
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace and what versions of each library you are using

Comment: @ianhanniballake Updated thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `setSupportActionBar()` with that Toolbar?

Comment: yes in `onCreate` of activity `setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Navigation UI guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar):

> **Caution**: If you pass a `Toolbar` as the argument to `setSupportActionBar()`, the `ActionBar` assumes complete ownership of that `Toolbar` and **you must not use any Toolbar APIs after that call.**

This is true in every case where you call `setSupportActionBar()`. This means that directly calling any `Toolbar` API, such as `setTitle`, is going to break that ownership contract and lead to these kind of exceptions.

Instead, you should either:

1. Don't use `setSupportActionBar()` at all. You can [connect a Toolbar to Navigation directly](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar) and upgrade to [AppCompat 1.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.4.0) to have fragments add elements to the Toolbar via the `MenuHost` and `MenuProvider` APIs.
2. If you use `setSupportActionBar()`, then you need to set the title via the ActionBar APIs. Namely, calling `supportActionBar!!.title = ...`
3. Follow the [app bar guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar) and set an `android:label` on each destination in your navigation graph XML file (i.e., `android:label="@string/fragmentTitle"`). This will automatically update the title as the current destination changes (assuming you've called the appropriate `setup` method of `NavigationUI`). This would remove the need to use your listener at all, thus allowing you to delete all of your code entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are correct. I have 1 `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)`
2 `binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)` and 3 `setSupportActionBar`. I removed the first one with `binding.toolbar`, then even use `binding.toolbar` it works.